# How can I make `cd` in macOS use the correct case of directory names?

Tags: macos, shell, cd

I know that [macOS's default file system is case-insensitive](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/22304/77873). Because of this, if I have a directory named `~/Test`; `cd ~/test` and `cd ~/TeSt` will work and change my shell's current directory to the `~/Test` directory. However, my shell "sees" my current working directory as the original case I `cd`'d to. The output of `pwd`, output of `echo $PWD`, and my shell prompt all show the "incorrect" casing (tested in `bash` and `zsh`).

Is there a way to make my shell or the `cd` command use the actual casing of the directory I'm navigating to?

I want to be able to `cd ~/test`, and have `basename $(pwd)` (and my prompt, etc) show `Test` instead `test`.

Comment: This is probably [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for Stack Overflow. Perhaps https://unix.stackexchange.com.

Comment: `pwd -P` will get you the physical directory, which will have capitalization fixed (but obviously losing symbolic links in the process).